What is this wall surface in my bathroom?
Looking for help identifying this material and how to remove it.
I replaced my bathroom vanity but created a bigger job in the meantime. The vanities were different sizes so I created a gap in the tile. Since the house is old I probably can’t exactly patch the old tile. Now I’m left with this exposed patch behind the vanity. There was two layers of tile and then I hit what seems like plaster or concrete. I’m afraid to smash into it without knowing what it is.
I’d also like to replace the pipes under the sink because they are old and corroded but to do this I’d have to break down whatever this wall is. We had our shower professionally done and they didn’t mention anything about plaster or concrete.


If you want to know the wall construction and intend on demolishing it, or at least a patch of it, you can use a cold chisel or a saw to remove a chunk and you'll see.  It's probably plaster, maybe 2 or 3 layers of different compounds, over some backing like wood lath, wire mesh, fiberboard, etc.   To replace the pipes you may need to turn this into a major renovation.  If this is a first floor and you have an unfinished basement or crawl space you might be lucky and be able to renew the plumbing without breaking more wall.

It's probably concrete. You can know for sure if you have any towel or toilet paper holders seemingly built into the tile.
It's probably half an inch thick and you'll want to use an angle grinder or circular saw with a diamond blade to cut it out. Did this for a bathroom in my house and replaced it all with drywall. There were regular studs behind it. You will have scars for any of the board remaining. Since your tile is white, just paint it white. It won't stand out horribly if you do.
